# How to extract package name from filepath with Apache Ant?

Tags: java, android, ant, path, ant-contrib

I want to convert file path to android package name like from below given file path :

> **F:\PartnerFolders\modify\src\com\builder\components\AlwaysFocusedText.java**

i want to convert

> \com\builder\components\

to

> com.builder.components

and move that file to converted package

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you find the `indexOf` `src` and with the respective offset `replaceAll` \ with .

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged ant-contrib, so you could just use 2 propertyregexs, if for example your file path is defined in a property:

```
<property name="file.path" value="F:\PartnerFolders\modify\src\com\builder\components\AlwaysFocusedText.java"/>
```

You could then get your desired package name with the following code:

```
<propertyregex property="stripped.file.path" input="${file.path}" regexp=".*\\src\\(.*)\\.*\.java" select="\1"/>
<propertyregex property="package" input="${stripped.file.path}" regexp="\\" replace="." global="true"/>
```

The first propertyregex will strip out the string: **\com\builder\components\**  and store it in the property **stripped.file.path**. The `select="\1"` selects the first group, i.e. what is contained within the first parentheses in the **regexp**.
The second propertyregex will replace the **\** with **.** and store it in the property **package**.